# How to make login form with admin and different user in php?

Tags: php, mysql, session

Hi developed a admin login an user login page in php when i loged in as a admin it work perfect and when i loged in as a user then it always  give same user name  on screen  but all time username is different in db

Here is my code

**login.php**

```
<?php
include('conn.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$UserName=$_POST['user'];
$PassWord=$_POST['pass'];

//echo $UserName;
 //echo $PassWord;
$sql = "SELECT role from login WHERE username='$UserName'and password='$PassWord'";
//$sql=mysql_query("select usertype from login where username='$UserType' and password='$Password'")or die (mysql_error());//query sang database 
$retval = mysql_query($sql);
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

 session_start();
                $_SESSION["user"]=$UserName;
                $_SESSION["pass"]=$PassWord ;
                $_SESSION['role']=$row['role'];
                $_SESSION['eid']=$row['eid'];
if ($row['role']==0){
 header("location:admin.php");
                        }
                        elseif ($row['role']==1) {
                       header("location:testing.php");
                        }

                        } 
}
echo "Invalid User Name and Password\n";

?>
```

**Testing.php**

```
<?php
include('conn.php');
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['role'])){
header('location:index.php');
}
//
?>
<a href="logout.php">logout</a>
</br>
</br>
<?php
//mag show sang information sang user nga nag login
$role=$_SESSION['role'];
$eid=$_SESSION['eid'];
$result=mysql_query("select * from login where role='$role'")or die(mysql_error);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$UserName=$row['username'];
echo $UserName;
?>
```

my problem is that  when i loged in as user then user name should print on screen

How can i achieve my goal

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is **zero** security in this implementation because you've created numerous hazardously bad [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). A better plan would be to use a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that comes with an [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) that is actually secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from login where role='$role'")or die(mysql_error);
```

This query will only show the first user, no matter what

You already stored the username in the session, so just echo

```
$_SESSION['user'];
```

and you will get the logged in username

```
<?php
include('conn.php');
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['role'])){
header('location:index.php');
}
//
?>
<a href="logout.php">logout</a>
</br>
</br>
<?php
//mag show sang information sang user nga nag login

echo $_SESSION['user'];
?>
```

Comment: You already did the query in login.php.  Once you send the post data to login.php, your session variable $_SESSION['user']; will contain the information you want.  There is no need to query again in testing.php

Answer (score 0):

### Into your login.php code

You need to update your query by adding eid to your query

```
$sql = 'SELECT role, eid from login WHERE username = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($UserName).'" AND password = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($PassWord).'" ';
```

If user is found, you can store eid and role into your session, and **never** store password into session.

```
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die('Database error -> ' . mysql_error());  
if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query)
    $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['username'];
}
```

### Into your Testing.php code

You don't need to go to your database any more, just check your session to get the

```
echo $_SESSION['userName'];
```